# Скрыть сломанную картинку и показать ее альтернативный текст ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, изображения

Есть компонент, показывает список элементов из Json.

```
const Contact = ({avatar, first_name, last_name, email}) => {
    const initials = first_name.charAt(0)+""+last_name.charAt(0);

    return (
        <ListGroupItem className="item">
            <div>
                <Image src={avatar} alt={initials} className="avatar" />
            </div>
            <div className="info">
                <p>{first_name} {last_name}</p>
                <p>{email}</p>
            </div>
        </ListGroupItem>
    );
};
```

У некоторых из этих картинок путь равен `null`.
Сейчас у меня выводятся битые картинки рядом с альтернативным текстом. Как можно скрыть битые изображения и показать только `alt`, который установлен на `initials`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы можете делать ([Условный рендеринг](https://ru.reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html#inline-if-else-with-conditional-operator)):

```
{avatar ? <Image src={avatar} alt={initials} className="avatar" /> : initials}
```

Comment: @AjeetShan Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
const Contact = ({avatar, first_name, last_name, email}) => {
    const initials = first_name.charAt(0)+""+last_name.charAt(0);

    return (
        <ListGroupItem className="item">
            <div>
                { 
                  null !== avatar 
                    ? <Image src={avatar} alt={initials} className="avatar" /> 
                    : initials 
                }
            </div>
            <div className="info">
                <p>{first_name} {last_name}</p>
                <p>{email}</p>
            </div>
        </ListGroupItem>
    );
};
```